# VBA Word The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is a problem similar to several already posted. I need specific help though since I don't know how to apply the answers to other questions.

Basically, I'm writing code in Access that references MSWord, and if I run the code multiple times, it starts failing with the message

> The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CreateWordMergeDoc_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_CreateWordMergeDoc_Click

Dim strSQL, strChurch, strDistLang, strFind, strReplace As String
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wrdMergeDoc As Word.Document
Dim strFilepath As String

strFilepath = "O:\Church Phone List"

'Require choice for church and district
If IsNull(Me![ChurchCombo]) = True Then
    MsgBox "Select church", , "Church Phone List"
    Me.ChurchCombo.SetFocus
    GoTo CloseSub
End If

strChurch = Me![ChurchCombo]
strDistLang = Me![DistrictChoiceCombo]

If strDistLang = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select District", , "Church Phone List"
    Me.DistrictChoiceCombo.SetFocus
    GoTo CloseSub
Else
    strDistLang = IIf(Me![DistrictChoiceCombo] = "", "Church", Me![DistrictChoiceCombo])
End If

'Create SQL string from present church/district information
strSQL = "SELECT Churches.* " & vbCrLf & _
"FROM Churches " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (((Churches.Church)='" & strChurch & "') AND ((Churches.[District/Language])Like'" & strDistLang & "')) " & vbCrLf & _
"ORDER BY Churches.NAME;"

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True

Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(strFilepath & "\Phone Merge Document.docx")

With wrdDoc

    With .ActiveWindow
        'Open the header/footer and add the church (and district if appropriate)
        .ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
        .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        .Selection.TypeText Text:=strChurch & IIf(strDistLang <> "Church", " (" & strDistLang & ")", "")
        'Close header/footer
        .ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument
    End With

    With .MailMerge
        .MainDocumentType = wdCatalog
        .OpenDataSource NAME:= _
            GetNamePath _
            , ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
            WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
            "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & strFilepath & "2017\Phone List 2017.mdb;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;" _
            , SQLStatement:=strSQL, SubType:= _
           wdMergeSubTypeOther

        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End With

    With wrdApp
        .Selection.WholeStory
        With .Selection.ParagraphFormat
            .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
            .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        End With
        .Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
        .ActiveDocument.DefaultTabStop = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        'Add a tab stop
        .Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(0.1), _
            Alignment:=wdAlignTabLeft, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces

        'Replace (C) and (¢) with [C] and [c] since auto replace for (c) may be enabled
        .Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With .Selection.Find
            .Text = "(C)"
            .Replacement.Text = "[C]"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        .Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        With .Selection.Find
            .Text = "(¢)"
            .Replacement.Text = "[c]"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        .Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        'Lock document so track changes stays on
        .ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="onebody1", NoReset:=False, Type:= _
             wdAllowOnlyRevisions, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False
        .ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
         strFilepath & "\Track-Change Documents\"
    End With

    strFind = "/"
    strReplace = " "

    strDistLang = Replace(strDistLang, strFind, strReplace)

     wrdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=strChurch & IIf(strDistLang <> "Church", " - " & strDistLang, ""), FileFormat _
        :=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=14

    wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Activate

'quit the word application:

wrdApp.Quit

MsgBox "Completed", , "Church Phone List"

CloseSub:

'Clear the object variables:

Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing

Exit_CreateWordMergeDoc_Click:
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_CreateWordMergeDoc_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CreateWordMergeDoc_Click

End Sub
```

I'd be quite thankful if someone could help clean up the code with regard to the error message.

Comment: This seemed to work! My testing was limited, but I didn't have any more error messages. I am very grateful for your assistance!!!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your problem is likely due to the calls to the unqualified `InchesToPoints` methods.

It doesn't appear (from what I can see on MSDN) that Access' `Application` object includes that method, and therefore it is defaulting to using the method which is part of the `Word.Application` object.  This will create an instance of that object that isn't being released at the end of your program.

The easiest fix is to simply qualify the call by specifying that you want to use the late-bound `Word.Application` object you create, i.e. use `wrdApp.InchesToPoints`.

Comment: Just putting a period before InchesToPoints worked just fine.Thanks again!